# Ruby wrapper (open3) - how to capture live user input while script is in progress?

Tags: ruby, pipe, stdin

I'm trying to write a wrapper script to tie together the function of 4 related scripts. Normally we have to run these 4 scripts in order to achieve a certain state, but I would like to wrap these 4 scripts into 1.

However, all of these scripts require user input - most notably, y/n prompts at several stages of execution. I would still like these questions to be answered by the user and have the current-running script respond accordingly.

However, I don't see any way for this to come from a user during execution of the script. All the examples show stdin being passed to the script before execution, such as:

```
o, s = Open3.capture2("factor", :stdin_data=>"42")
p o #=> "42: 2 3 7\n"
```

I'm wondering if maybe the definition of pipe means it cannot come from real stdin such as they keyboard, but must be passed in (piped in) before execution. Is this a correct assumption? And if so -- is there a way to wrap scripts in ruby in such a way that they can still accept and respond to user input? I've also tried backticks to no avail, I'm starting to wonder if this is not possible.

Comment: Have you tried the `popen` methods in Open3?

Comment: Yes, I have. I only used capture2 because it had a clearer example, but all of the other open3 methods don't seem to allow input captured from the user during runtime.

Comment: But wouldn't you capture the input and forward it to the script through a pipe?